# Xstream.toXML() XMLGregorianCalendar should not have child elements

Tags: java, xml, xstream

Below is the sample code.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws DatatypeConfigurationException {
        GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        XMLGregorianCalendar xmlBirthDt = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendarDate(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), 
                                    cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1, cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED);
        XStream x = new XStream();
        x.alias("date", XMLGregorianCalendar.class);
        x.addDefaultImplementation(com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl.class, javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar.class);
        String g = x.toXML(xmlBirthDt);

        System.out.println(g);

    }
}
```

And below is the output

```
<date>
    <year>2018</year>
    <month>10</month>
    <day>15</day>
    <timezone>-2147483648</timezone>
    <hour>-2147483648</hour>
    <minute>-2147483648</minute>
    <second>-2147483648</second>
</date>
```

Below is what I'm expecting (when the generated XML is validated against the schema, it is throwing errors: element date has child elements which is not accepted)

```
<date>10-15-2018</date>
```

I can't change the libraries used or change the schema as this is a modification to the existing huge code base. Please help me.

Comment: why dont you create your own XMLGregorianCalendar  object and add only what you want inside? so you can control the data passed.

Comment: @Sir.Hedgehog I have made changes to the code. Please check it now.

Comment: you could try sth like XMLGregorianCalendar xgc = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(new DateTime().toGregorianCalendar()); and where new DateTime add your DateTime or even .now if you like to test it first passing data.

Comment: @Sir.Hedgehog it didn't make any difference. when you print the object, it is giving the data like that (toString() method is giving the correct output). but when converting to xml, child elements are showing up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by implementing Converter and registering with Xstream. Below is the final code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws DatatypeConfigurationException {
    GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    XMLGregorianCalendar xmlBirthDt = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendarDate(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), 
                                cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1, cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED);

    XStream x = new XStream();
    x.alias("date", com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl.class);
    x.registerConverter(new Converter() {
        @Override
        public boolean canConvert(Class arg0) {
            return arg0.equals(com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl.class);
        }

        @Override
        public Object unmarshal(HierarchicalStreamReader arg0, UnmarshallingContext arg1) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void marshal(Object arg0, HierarchicalStreamWriter arg1, MarshallingContext arg2) {
            XMLGregorianCalendar x = (XMLGregorianCalendar) arg0;
            arg1.setValue(x.toString());
        }
    });

    String g = x.toXML(xmlBirthDt);

    System.out.println(g);
}
```